# Can't switch from Calendar month view to day

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

From the calendar month view, I can't select a date, and jump to the day view.

Running iOS 9.0.2 on iPhone 6

Comment: My overview icon is off and I can't open individual days either. Started as soon as the update happened and of course since the update it's told me to update 3 more times!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you have the 'overview' icon at the top of the screen on or off.

If it's On, your day view is underneath the Month...

[image]

---

If it's Off, then tapping a day will take you to the Day View

[image]

---

unless the same icon is also On in Day View, in which case it will go to Event List view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found another thread on it - you have to tap QUICKLY to open day view. Double-tapping works because the first tap is fast enough.

Seems to be an iOS 9 issue.